# Open directory from ls result

Tags: command-line, cd, ls

I have a problem, I would like to pipe ls and cd together. I create shell pipe like:

```
cesta = ls -lat | awk 'NR==2 {print $8"/"}'
cd $cesta
```

But it doesn't work. Could you help me. And I didn't receive any error.
Filip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues with what you're attempting. First of all, to set a variable's value, you can't have spaces around the `=`. Then, in order to capture the output of a command you need either backtics, or preferably `$()`.

Finally, and most importantly, [you should not parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), it is very hard to do well and extremely prone to errors. Your approach will break if your directory name contains a space for example. In the examples below, what is the `8th` field?

```
 $ ls -l
 total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Nov 11 14:59 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Nov 11  2013 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Nov 11 15:00 file 2
                                    -----
                                      |--------> 8th field
```

The file/directory name might be the 9th field, or it might be the 9th and 10th fields, or even more. Plus, the date format can change between locales. Basically, using `ls` for this is a horrible idea. Instead, use `stat` and sort by time:

```
$ cesta=$(stat --printf "%X\t%n\n" * | sort -nk1,1 | cut -f 2- | awk 'NR==2')
$ cd "$cesta"
```

Comment: It is really nice idea with space in the name. Thanks for this and about the 8th field, in this filed I have the name of folder, because I am doing it on server throw ssh and there is different than on your local PC. But thank you for it.

Comment: @FilipZembol exactly, that's why you _shouldn't parse ls_. You can't depend on it on different machines. Even on the same machine, depending on your `ls`, it can change between directories. Just don't do it, seriously.

Answer (score 0):

What's the output of your command?

```
ls -lat | awk 'NR==2 {print $8"/"}'
```

In my case I had the hour of when the directory was created.

Using [command substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution) it worked for me:

```
$ ABCD=`ls -lat | awk 'NR==2 {print $9"/"}'`
$ cd $ABCD
$ pwd
$ /home/myuser_name/.gconfd
```

Cheers,
Hugo.

Comment: Output from ls -lat | .... is name of folder which was last time created with / at the end of the name. After that I would like to use cd to open this name, which was called and see it in terminal....

Comment: Yes, but if I run:

$ ls -lat | awk 'NR==2 {print $8"/"}'

I got:

08:24/

Comment: So change the $8 to $9 and you receive the column for the name of the folders..Sorry for that, but the name of folders is for me at $8.. It depends.. But what you wrote doesnt work for me...

Comment: humm....

what do you have if you do: echo $cesta

Comment: Good question :-( empty row, but do you know why, because ls -lat ... wrote me what I want.. I have to sign it or eval it or something like this?

Comment: can you copy from here and try: cesta=\`ls -lat | awk 'NR==2 {print $8"/"}'`

Comment: I did it and it is OK, so I did not understand where I have problem but now it is working. Thank you for your time and for your skilled help.

Comment: Great :-) No probs. Cheers!

Comment: Please don't recommend parsing `ls`. It is basically impossible to do safely. Consider a directory called `dir 1` for example.

Comment: @terdon: As a rule of thumb yes. It's alright to parse the output of `ls -1` imho, because the output isn't arranged in columns. With `ls -1at | head -n 1` one would get the most recently modified directory entry without knowing about `stat --printf` or `sort`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster only if the name of the file/directory contains no `\n` characters. You also get the wrong name if it contains any of `\r`, `\t`. Oh, and you can't do it with `head -n 1`, that will print the current directory, `.`. You would need something like `ls -1at | head -2 | tail -n1` but that still breaks on newlines. Believe me, we've [flogged this horse](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/22222) to death on U&L. It _might_ be possible to do safely and portably but you need to really know what you're doing and even then it's likely to break.